# Optional arrows in igraph

Tags: python, igraph

Consider I have the following graph:

```
g = Graph()
g.add_vertex('Burglary')
g.add_vertex('Earthquake')
g.add_vertex('Alarm')
g.add_vertex('John')
g.add_vertex('Marry')

g.vs["label"] = g.vs["name"]

g.add_edge('Burglary','Alarm')
g.add_edge('Earthquake','Alarm')
g.add_edge('Alarm','John')
g.add_edge('Alarm','Marry')

layout = g.layout("kk")
plot(g, layout = layout, margin = 40)
```

How can I make part of the edges directed (not all). I know that If I set **g = Graph()** to **g = Graph().as_directed()**, it will make all the edges directed. However, I don't want that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't do that in igraph - the graph model itself stores whether the entire graph is directed or not. However, you can set the `arrow_size` attribute of some of the edges to zero so igraph will not draw arrowheads for these edges on the plot. (They will still be directed nevertheless).